# Unique Keys/Indexes in FuelPHP

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'm currently undergoing my first venture into FuelPHP and was wondering how I'd go about marking certain keys (e.g. username) in the model, and if it is possible to do so using oil. Particularly in terms of validation in the model, like:

```
protected static $_properties = array(
  'id',
  'name' => array(
     'data_type' => 'string',
     'label' => 'Name',
     'validation' => array('required', 'max_length'=>array(100), 'min_length'=>array(10)) //validation rules
  ),
  'username' => array(
     'data_type' => 'string',
     'label' => 'Username',
     'validation' => array('required', 'unique') // does this work?
  )
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would work, if there was a framework defined validation rule called 'unique'. But there isn't.

There is an example in the docs (http://docs.fuelphp.com/classes/validation/validation.html#/extending_validation) which explains how to add custom rules, and uses 'unique' as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with this excluding the current record that I am updating. So to resolve this I "hacked" it a little.

This works with Model_Crud, it should work with others with a little adaptation.

## The rule (in model/mymodel.php):

```
protected static $_rules = array(
  'uniqueField' => 'unique[Model_Product,code]', //unique[Model,fieldToCheck]
);
```

## The method (in myvalidation.php):

```
public static function _validation_unique($val, $model, $field)
{
  if (empty($val))
    return true;

  $findOpts = array(
    'where' => array(
      array($field, '=', $val)
    )
  );

  $input = \Validation::active()->input();

  if (! empty($input['id']))
    $findOpts['where'][] = array('id', '<>', $input['id']);

  \Validation::active()->set_message('unique', 'The field :label must be unique, but :value has already been used');

  //Model_Crud provides a find method which I use to find any of the duplicates
  $obj = call_user_func(array($model, 'find'), $findOpts);

  return ! count($obj) > 0;
}
```